# How to make CSS background responsive with certain dimensions

Tags: html, css

I'm creating a website and I am attempting to add a background image to the page that covers the entirety of the page and is responsive, yet I am having difficulty doing so. Whenever I tweak the width and height to match cover the entirety of the homepage, I obviously find that the dimensions don't scale when I move the page to another monitor, or make the window smaller. However, I need to tweak the width and height in order for the image to cover the page. Is there a way I could make the image responsive AND tweak the dimensions to my liking?

```css
#background-image-container {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-image-container">
  <img src="static/images/waco-siege2.jpg" id="background-image" style="opacity: 0.7; display: block;" width="1370" height="665">
</div>
```

I realize that my code is a mess and some parts may contradict other parts; but this just shows everything I have currently attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you're using an `<img>` element rather than a CSS background image, yet you're trying to style it with CSS.

Here's how you'd implement a CSS `background-image` which can responsively cover your entire page. Also note that you'd need to change `background-size: contain` to `background-size: cover` to accomplish this.

```css
#background-image-container {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  z-index: 0;
  background-image: url('static/images/waco-siege2.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-image-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Your markup for what you are trying to do looks wrong to me.  You need to set the background on the container element, not place the image inside of it.

`<div id="background-image-container" style="background-image:url(static/images/waco-siege2.jpg)"></div>`

I also think you'll want to use  background-size:cover instead of contain.

You could also just set the image width and height to 100%, but that would distort the image if it changes the aspect ratio.

Answer (score 1):

The other alternative to above, if you wanted to use the image (can be useful for thumbnails) is object-fit.

I've stripped most the other styles out just for the simplicity of the example.
You'll need to define a width and height on the parent container of the image for the object-fit to work too though.

```css
#background-image-container {
    display: block;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vh;
}

#background-image-container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="background-image-container">
  <img src="static/images/waco-siege2.jpg" id="background-image">
</div>
```